# adding a simple feature to a highcharts.js time series plot

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, time-series, data-visualization

I found this live updating time series chart and I’m trying to add a simple feature. I want to add a vertical line where the lowest point on the chart is. I found some code to add a vertical line but I’m not sure how to approach finding the lowest point and than updating the chart. look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pnL6xtLb/), I’m feel like I'm pretty close.

Highcharts.js code to add vertical line

```
 xAxis: {
       type: 'datetime',
        tickPixelInterval: 150,
        plotLines: [{ // this code adds a vertical line 
          color: '#FF0000', // Red
          width: 2,
          value: (new Date).getTime() // Position, you'll have to translate this to the values on your x axis
        }]
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a truly worthy question that I enjoyed researching. I did some sleuthing and discovered a way to add a plotline whenever the lowest value to date in the time series is generated.

First, I set a variable called `lowestValue` outside of your chart options. This variable will be used and checked as new points are added to the series.

```
// make the initial value higher that the possible maximum y value
var lowestValue = 10;
```

Next, I added some code to your chart events that checks to see whether the new `y` value that's generated is lower than the current value of `lowestValue`. If it is, we'll add a new plot line affixed to that point.

I also added code to remove the last plot line that was created (if there was one) to clearly show which point has the lowest value thus far. The key to doing this is to give the plot line you're adding a consistent `id`. This way, the `removePlotLine()` function knows which one to remove.

```
events: {
    load: function () {

        // set up the updating of the chart each second
        var series = this.series[0];
        setInterval(function () {
            var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                y = Math.random();
            series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);

            // if the most recent point is lower than 
            // the last recorded lowest value, add a 
            // new plotline
            if (y < lowestValue) {
                lowestValue = y;
              var plotOption = {
                  color: '#FF0000',
                  width: 2,
                  value: x,
                  zIndex: 0,
                  id: 'thisPlotLine'
              };
             // remove the previous plot line
             series.xAxis.removePlotLine('thisPlotLine');
             // add the new plot line
             series.xAxis.addPlotLine(plotOption);
            }

        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

I modified your fiddle to show these changes: http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/pnL6xtLb/2/

Now, you'll notice that, over time, your plot lines may appear more infrequently as the value of `lowestValue` gets closer to 0. If you'd rather show the **lowest value among the points visible in the chart at any given time**, I'd suggest adding a counter that keeps track of the number of points that have been added since the last plot line was added. Then, if the lowest point (with its plot line) is moved off the chart, reset `lowestValue` back to 10 so the lowest **visible** point is the one that gets the plot line.

I hope this information is helpful to you!

Comment: Thank You! this is an excellent answer and exactly what I was looking for. @brightmatrix

Comment: I'm so glad! Please let me know if there's any other questions you have for which I can help out.